# Multiple services handling a request type

Tags: routes, servicestack

I need for the sake of a decoupled architecture to call a different service using the same request dto.

Eg.

```
// A value type has a callback url that will validate the request
public class ValueType {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string CallbackUrl {get;set;}
}

// The request dto to validate a value
public class ValidateRequest : IReturn<ValidateResponse>{
   public string ValueTypeId {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}

// The validation response
public class ValidateResponse {
   public bool IsValid {get;set;}
}
```

I want to be able to handle these in multiple services:

```
public class Service1 : Service {
    public object Get(ValidateRequest input){
        return new ValidateResponse(input.Value === "ABC")
    }
}

public class Service2 : Service {
    public object Get(ValidateRequest input){
        return new ValidateResponse(input.Value === "DEF")
    }
}
```

The validation calls would be submitted in another service:

```
public class AnotherService : Service{

public object Post(ARequest input){

    var valueType = _valueTypeRepo.Get(input.type);
    var callbackUrl = valueType.callbackUrl;
    // callbackUrl = '/api/service1/validate' or '/api/service2/validate'
    // Here, I want to call either Service1 or Service2 based on runtime condition
    var jsonClient= new JsonClient(callbackUrl);
    jsonClient.Get(new ValidateRequest())...

}

}
```

How can I register multiple routes to handle this?

[image: Example of architecture]

Here, InvoiceService "knows" about CustomerService. But CustomerService doesn't hold a dependency on "InvoiceService". This is what I mean by decoupled architecture. Multiple services could add custom fields (or even users could add custom fields with validation url being an external API entirely), without "CustomerService" having to have a dependency on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single Service class can provide the implementation of a Request DTO, if you need it in different files you can use partial classes. They’re also can only be a single implementation for a Request DTO, each of which [can have multiple routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing).

If you absolutely need to you can have other Request DTOs inherit from the same Request DTO but as [they’re already declarative I would avoid inheritance](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos#dry-vs-intent) and just have them implement the same interface if you want them to be able to share the same validation logic.

I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to achieve with your runtime proxy/delegation implementation, but if you want to call another Service use the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) instead of a Service Client which saves the overhead of a HTTP Service call for internal Services. If you need to convert a Request DTO with shared properties into a different Request DTO you can use [ServiceStack's built-in Auto Mapping](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping), so you can convert a Request DTO into a different Request DTO with shared properties and call its Service with:

```
var response = Gateway.Send(request.ConvertTo<MyRequest2>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I am trying to acheive is as follow: In a multi-tenant architecture, a CustomerService stores all information relating to a tenant's customer. The tenant can at runtime definecustom "fields" for his customers (Say, an clientNo ...). Perhaps this tenant wants my application to validate the value of that clientNo against an external API. In the definition of that custom field, the tenant specifies the "validationUrl" that the application should call to validate the value.

Comment: Also, it would be possible that another *in-process* service, say InvoiceService, would register a customer custom field on the behalf of a tenant. This field, say accountId, would have a validationUrl being the url of InvoiceService. This way, CustomerService doesn't have to know anything about InvoiceService, it would only hold a validationUrl that it would call whenever a customer's accountId would be set. CustomerService would expect whatever url it calls to return a standard response (specified by a Request / Response dto)

Comment: Would it be possible (for in-process), to use `/api?/[xml|json|html|jsv|csv]/[reply|oneway]/[servicename]` (as specified by the page you linked in your answer)? 

If so, in that case, the custom field definition would have a validationUrl of `/api/json/reply/invoice`. CustomerService, upon trying to modify the value of a customer's accountId, would call this url.

Comment: @LudovicC I'd recommend against having a generic Service that delegates to other services, it makes your architecture unnecessarily complex and harder for API consumers to discover and consume APIs who wont be able to send Request DTOs as per normal. IMO any reusable/shared logic you want should be in code, not distorting external APIs and having them all go through a single Service. You can use [Wild Card paths](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#wildcard-paths) to have a Service accept multiple paths with a single route definition, but it's not an approach I'd take.

Comment: What do you mean by distorting APIs? Also, the product I am working on is quite complex. The ability to add metadata (in the form of custom fields) on the Customer entity at runtime is a must - especially for enterprise customers that need integrations. This arch. is also the approach used by Jira for Issue custom fields with callback urls to validate a custom field value or even to get autocompletion... I'm not sure how to accomplish this without getting in dependency hell...!

Comment: @LudovicC Going through a single API to call other APIs is unnatural, consumers should just be calling the API they want directly, any shared logic should be in code, using shared dependencies, C# extension methods, etc as per normal C# code. There's also a number of [Request/Response Filters](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) that can be used to run custom logic against multiple different services. You can make your single services as dynamic as you want, but I wouldn't be routing them all through a single service.

Comment: I'm sorry but I beg to differ. I know of numerous examples of API logic calling other APIs. All Cloud provider services (RDS, KMS, IAM, Google Geocoding, Mongo..). From my experience, a webserver almost more often than not makes other API calls in the process of responding to a request. I probably didn't express my requirements clearly. Basically, I want to be able to add metadata to an existing entity, but the validation logic should be executed by another service/API, which might be in process or running elsewhere. This "external" API could be private (only accepting "internal" connections).

Comment: But I understand that you're advising me against building a generic monster. Which I totally agree on.

Comment: @LudovicC I'm not saying APIs can't call other Services if that's what it needs to do, I'm saying don't have all API consumers call a single endpoint to call other Services. I don't see why your Service doesn't have the additional properties it needs that the implementation inspects to change how it deals with it, in which case additional Request DTO properties doesn't impact the Service routes. i.e. its an implementation concern that doesn't affect the API surface.